# How to get whole sentence that contain particular word?

Tags: java, nlp, information-retrieval

I want to get whole sentence and paragraph by finding word. 
For eg: If I search "released" in text "Hundreds of political prisoners have been released, and censorship rules have been relaxed. The EU and US have lifted the majority of sanctions against Burma as a result. " 
it should to return "Hundreds of political prisoners have been released, and censorship rules have been relaxed." and whole paragraph as well.

Comment: You can use `contains`: "*Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.*"

Comment: Not sure whats the context.. How do you identify a paragraph.. are your text enclosed within <p> .. </p> ?

Comment: from where will you search?

Comment: Why so many votes to close? Seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: I agree with Maroun and sanbhat. Seems like the simplist way would be to split your string into sentences (split on `.!?`) and paragraphs (what marker is being used?) and use `contains` in each. You might be able to use a regular expression but is would be complex and error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `indexOf`, then search backwards and forwards for the separator of the paragraph. Might be `<p>` or `\n`.

```
public static String findParagraph(String source, String searchText, String paragraphSeparator)
{
    final int locationOfSearchTerm = source.indexOf(searchText);
    if (locationOfSearchTerm == -1) return null;

    int paragraphEnd = source.indexOf(paragraphSeparator, locationOfSearchTerm + searchText.length);

    //if we didn't find an end of a paragraph, we want to go the end
    if (paragraphEnd == -1) paragraphEnd = searchText.length;

    int paragraphStart = source.lastIndexOf(paragraphSeparator, locationOfSearchTerm);

    //if we didn't find a start of a paragraph, we want to go the beginning
    if (paragraphStart == -1) paragraphStart = 0;

    return searchText.subString(paragraphStart, paragraphEnd - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How structured is your data?

You can probably get paragraphs by looking for 1-2+ new line characters. For sentences you are going to need to do some [text segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segmentation#Sentence_segmentation). For example, using the NLTK library for Python you can use a pre-trained [Punkt sentence segment-er](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html), which is trained on a large corpus in order to learn that things like `Mr.` and `U.S.A.` do not mark the end of a sentence even though they contain periods (see this question: [Python split text on sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576077/1988505)).

Once you can segment your text into paragraphs and sentences, you need to decide if you just want to do a linear pass over your corpus, or more likely index your data using [information retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) techniques, such as by building an [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index), or by using an existing solution like [Apache Lunce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene).

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of way to do this. Here is one :

Create a map wich associate a sentence and a paragraph :

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Hundreds of political prisoners have been released, and censorship rules have been relaxed.", The EU and US have lifted the majority of sanctions against Burma as a result.);
...
```

Once you have built a map with all your texts you can search this way :

```
public Map<String, String> searchInSentence(String toFind, Map<String, String> texts){
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(Entry<String, String> entry : texts.entrySet(){
       if(entry.getKey().contains(toFind){
           result.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

It will return a Map where the sentence is the key and the paragraph is the value.