# What is the difference between corpus and lexicon in NLTK (python)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, nltk, corpus, lexical

Can someone tell me the difference between a **Corpora** ,**corpus** and **lexicon** in NLTK ?

What is the **movie data set** ?

what is **Wordnet** ?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: hey Rohit, thx for the comment...I added this though as they are all related...answeting one in context of the others would help  I beleive...

Comment: It's not `machine-learning` per se but it's more NLTK and nlp.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Corpora** is the *plural* for corpus.

**Corpus** basically means a body, and in the context of Natural Language Processing (NLP), it means a body of text.

(source: https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=corpora)

---

**Lexicon** is a vocabulary, a list of words, a dictionary (source: https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=lexicon)

In NLTK, any lexicon is considered a corpus since *a list of words* is also *a body of text*. E.g. a list of stopwords can be found in NLTK corpus API:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> print stopwords.words('english')
[u'i', u'me', u'my', u'myself', u'we', u'our', u'ours', u'ourselves', u'you', u'your', u'yours', u'yourself', u'yourselves', u'he', u'him', u'his', u'himself', u'she', u'her', u'hers', u'herself', u'it', u'its', u'itself', u'they', u'them', u'their', u'theirs', u'themselves', u'what', u'which', u'who', u'whom', u'this', u'that', u'these', u'those', u'am', u'is', u'are', u'was', u'were', u'be', u'been', u'being', u'have', u'has', u'had', u'having', u'do', u'does', u'did', u'doing', u'a', u'an', u'the', u'and', u'but', u'if', u'or', u'because', u'as', u'until', u'while', u'of', u'at', u'by', u'for', u'with', u'about', u'against', u'between', u'into', u'through', u'during', u'before', u'after', u'above', u'below', u'to', u'from', u'up', u'down', u'in', u'out', u'on', u'off', u'over', u'under', u'again', u'further', u'then', u'once', u'here', u'there', u'when', u'where', u'why', u'how', u'all', u'any', u'both', u'each', u'few', u'more', u'most', u'other', u'some', u'such', u'no', u'nor', u'not', u'only', u'own', u'same', u'so', u'than', u'too', u'very', u's', u't', u'can', u'will', u'just', u'don', u'should', u'now']
```

---

The **movie review dataset** in NLTK (canonically known as `Movie Reviews Corpus`) is a *text dataset of 2k movie reviews with sentiment polarity classification* (source: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html)

And it is often used for tutorial purposes for introduction to NLP and sentiment analysis, see http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html and [nltk NaiveBayesClassifier training for sentiment analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827741/nltk-naivebayesclassifier-training-for-sentiment-analysis)

---

**WordNet** is *lexical database for the English language* (it's like a lexicon/dictionary with word-to-word relations) (source: https://wordnet.princeton.edu/).

In NLTK, it incorporates the Open Multilingual WordNet (http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/) that allows you to query the words in other languages.

Since it is also a list of words (in this case with many other things included, relations, lemmas, POS, etc.), it's also invoked using `nltk.corpus` in NLTK.

The canonical idiom to use the wordnet in NLTK is as such:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('dog')
[Synset('dog.n.01'), Synset('frump.n.01'), Synset('dog.n.03'), Synset('cad.n.01'), Synset('frank.n.02'), Synset('pawl.n.01'), Synset('andiron.n.01'), Synset('chase.v.01')]
```

---

The easiest way to understand/learn the NLP jargons and the basics is to go through these tutorial in the NLTK book: http://www.nltk.org/book/