# How to tag an article with NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to understand how to tag an article via the NLTK. According to [bullet point 2.7](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) explains how 
to find the most frequent nouns.

```
def findtags(tag_prefix, tagged_text):
    cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((tag, word) for (word, tag) in tagged_text
                                  if tag.startswith(tag_prefix))
    return dict((tag, cfd[tag].most_common(5)) for tag in cfd.conditions())


>>> tagdict = findtags('NN', nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_words(categories='news'))
>>> for tag in sorted(tagdict):
...     print(tag, tagdict[tag])
```

But this is really confusing as I don't see how a piece of text is being injected in to find the tags for it.  Rather it is using a predefined structure of data (nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_words). Not sure how to proceed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**:

To tag a text, use `nltk.pos_tag` but do note its quirks ([Python NLTK pos_tag not returning the correct part-of-speech tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821188/python-nltk-pos-tag-not-returning-the-correct-part-of-speech-tag)):

```
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> text = "This is a foo bar piece of text. And there are many sentences in this text."
>>> tagged_text = [pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)) for sent in sent_tokenize(text)]
>>> tagged_text
[[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('foo', 'NN'), ('bar', 'NN'), ('piece', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('text', 'NN'), ('.', '.')], [('And', 'CC'), ('there', 'EX'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('many', 'JJ'), ('sentences', 'NNS'), ('in', 'IN'), ('this', 'DT'), ('text', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]]
```

---

**In long**:

A list of NLTK datasets can be found by:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

And `nltk.corpus.brown` corpus is one of the most commonly used corpus for Natural Language Processing or text processing (see [What is the difference between corpus and lexicon in NLTK (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526644/what-is-the-difference-between-corpus-and-lexicon-in-nltk-python/31526744#31526744) for jargons).

In the case of brown corpus, it is a fully tagged and tokenized corpus so all NLTK provided was a reader. To access the various annotations, see **section 1.3** at http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html, here's a few examples:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> brown.words()[:50]
[u'The', u'Fulton', u'County', u'Grand', u'Jury', u'said', u'Friday', u'an', u'investigation', u'of', u"Atlanta's", u'recent', u'primary', u'election', u'produced', u'``', u'no', u'evidence', u"''", u'that', u'any', u'irregularities', u'took', u'place', u'.', u'The', u'jury', u'further', u'said', u'in', u'term-end', u'presentments', u'that', u'the', u'City', u'Executive', u'Committee', u',', u'which', u'had', u'over-all', u'charge', u'of', u'the', u'election', u',', u'``', u'deserves', u'the', u'praise']
>>> brown.tagged_words()[:50]
[(u'The', u'AT'), (u'Fulton', u'NP-TL'), (u'County', u'NN-TL'), (u'Grand', u'JJ-TL'), (u'Jury', u'NN-TL'), (u'said', u'VBD'), (u'Friday', u'NR'), (u'an', u'AT'), (u'investigation', u'NN'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u"Atlanta's", u'NP$'), (u'recent', u'JJ'), (u'primary', u'NN'), (u'election', u'NN'), (u'produced', u'VBD'), (u'``', u'``'), (u'no', u'AT'), (u'evidence', u'NN'), (u"''", u"''"), (u'that', u'CS'), (u'any', u'DTI'), (u'irregularities', u'NNS'), (u'took', u'VBD'), (u'place', u'NN'), (u'.', u'.'), (u'The', u'AT'), (u'jury', u'NN'), (u'further', u'RBR'), (u'said', u'VBD'), (u'in', u'IN'), (u'term-end', u'NN'), (u'presentments', u'NNS'), (u'that', u'CS'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'City', u'NN-TL'), (u'Executive', u'JJ-TL'), (u'Committee', u'NN-TL'), (u',', u','), (u'which', u'WDT'), (u'had', u'HVD'), (u'over-all', u'JJ'), (u'charge', u'NN'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'election', u'NN'), (u',', u','), (u'``', u'``'), (u'deserves', u'VBZ'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'praise', u'NN')]
>>> brown.sents()
[[u'The', u'Fulton', u'County', u'Grand', u'Jury', u'said', u'Friday', u'an', u'investigation', u'of', u"Atlanta's", u'recent', u'primary', u'election', u'produced', u'``', u'no', u'evidence', u"''", u'that', u'any', u'irregularities', u'took', u'place', u'.'], [u'The', u'jury', u'further', u'said', u'in', u'term-end', u'presentments', u'that', u'the', u'City', u'Executive', u'Committee', u',', u'which', u'had', u'over-all', u'charge', u'of', u'the', u'election', u',', u'``', u'deserves', u'the', u'praise', u'and', u'thanks', u'of', u'the', u'City', u'of', u'Atlanta', u"''", u'for', u'the', u'manner', u'in', u'which', u'the', u'election', u'was', u'conducted', u'.'], ...]
>>> brown.sents()[:3]
[[u'The', u'Fulton', u'County', u'Grand', u'Jury', u'said', u'Friday', u'an', u'investigation', u'of', u"Atlanta's", u'recent', u'primary', u'election', u'produced', u'``', u'no', u'evidence', u"''", u'that', u'any', u'irregularities', u'took', u'place', u'.'], [u'The', u'jury', u'further', u'said', u'in', u'term-end', u'presentments', u'that', u'the', u'City', u'Executive', u'Committee', u',', u'which', u'had', u'over-all', u'charge', u'of', u'the', u'election', u',', u'``', u'deserves', u'the', u'praise', u'and', u'thanks', u'of', u'the', u'City', u'of', u'Atlanta', u"''", u'for', u'the', u'manner', u'in', u'which', u'the', u'election', u'was', u'conducted', u'.'], [u'The', u'September-October', u'term', u'jury', u'had', u'been', u'charged', u'by', u'Fulton', u'Superior', u'Court', u'Judge', u'Durwood', u'Pye', u'to', u'investigate', u'reports', u'of', u'possible', u'``', u'irregularities', u"''", u'in', u'the', u'hard-fought', u'primary', u'which', u'was', u'won', u'by', u'Mayor-nominate', u'Ivan', u'Allen', u'Jr.', u'.']]
>>> brown.tagged_sents()[:3]
[[(u'The', u'AT'), (u'Fulton', u'NP-TL'), (u'County', u'NN-TL'), (u'Grand', u'JJ-TL'), (u'Jury', u'NN-TL'), (u'said', u'VBD'), (u'Friday', u'NR'), (u'an', u'AT'), (u'investigation', u'NN'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u"Atlanta's", u'NP$'), (u'recent', u'JJ'), (u'primary', u'NN'), (u'election', u'NN'), (u'produced', u'VBD'), (u'``', u'``'), (u'no', u'AT'), (u'evidence', u'NN'), (u"''", u"''"), (u'that', u'CS'), (u'any', u'DTI'), (u'irregularities', u'NNS'), (u'took', u'VBD'), (u'place', u'NN'), (u'.', u'.')], [(u'The', u'AT'), (u'jury', u'NN'), (u'further', u'RBR'), (u'said', u'VBD'), (u'in', u'IN'), (u'term-end', u'NN'), (u'presentments', u'NNS'), (u'that', u'CS'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'City', u'NN-TL'), (u'Executive', u'JJ-TL'), (u'Committee', u'NN-TL'), (u',', u','), (u'which', u'WDT'), (u'had', u'HVD'), (u'over-all', u'JJ'), (u'charge', u'NN'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'election', u'NN'), (u',', u','), (u'``', u'``'), (u'deserves', u'VBZ'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'praise', u'NN'), (u'and', u'CC'), (u'thanks', u'NNS'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'City', u'NN-TL'), (u'of', u'IN-TL'), (u'Atlanta', u'NP-TL'), (u"''", u"''"), (u'for', u'IN'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'manner', u'NN'), (u'in', u'IN'), (u'which', u'WDT'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'election', u'NN'), (u'was', u'BEDZ'), (u'conducted', u'VBN'), (u'.', u'.')], [(u'The', u'AT'), (u'September-October', u'NP'), (u'term', u'NN'), (u'jury', u'NN'), (u'had', u'HVD'), (u'been', u'BEN'), (u'charged', u'VBN'), (u'by', u'IN'), (u'Fulton', u'NP-TL'), (u'Superior', u'JJ-TL'), (u'Court', u'NN-TL'), (u'Judge', u'NN-TL'), (u'Durwood', u'NP'), (u'Pye', u'NP'), (u'to', u'TO'), (u'investigate', u'VB'), (u'reports', u'NNS'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u'possible', u'JJ'), (u'``', u'``'), (u'irregularities', u'NNS'), (u"''", u"''"), (u'in', u'IN'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'hard-fought', u'JJ'), (u'primary', u'NN'), (u'which', u'WDT'), (u'was', u'BEDZ'), (u'won', u'VBN'), (u'by', u'IN'), (u'Mayor-nominate', u'NN-TL'), (u'Ivan', u'NP'), (u'Allen', u'NP'), (u'Jr.', u'NP'), (u'.', u'.')]]
```

The structure for:

- `nltk.corpus.brown.words()` is a list of string, where each item in the list is a word
- `nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_words()` is a list of tuples with the first element as the word and the 2nd element in the tuple as the tag
- `nltk.corpus.sents()` is a list of a list of string, where the other list comprises the whole corpus and the inner list is one sentence
- `nltk.corpus.tagged_sents()` is a list of list of tuples, where it's the same as `nltk.corpus.sents()` but the inner list is a tuple of word and tag.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer.  So Corpus is not just a sample file, it is actually needed to process the tagging? Looking at the nltk folder, even after deleting all zip files, the `corpus` folder alone is 1.4 gb. Is that all needed? Or could I just keep `brown` for best results? How about `models` folder? Is that needed too? 120mb

Comment: Depends on the task, if you only need the brown corpus, you could do `import nltk; nltk.download('brown')`. The other files in the `nltk_data` folder are used for other functions. But most probability, you'll need `punkt` for the `nltk.sent_tokenize` and also `maxent_treebank_pos_tagger` for `nltk.pos_tag` and possibly someday you'll need `universal_tagset` and `snowball_data`.

Comment: But if you like the idea of "batteries included", then just download all the models. As for corpus, it's also very useful if you're interested in using them as training data. I usually do `nltk.download('all')` so that I can get everything =)

Comment: Corpora (plural for corpus) in NLTK are already pre-process and zipped. NLTK provide the API to read them easily.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the info.  As I'm using the code on GoogleAppEngine, Hence there are some limitations and I need to prepare all Libs and data upfront I wish to upload.  So when you say they are zipped and NLTK can read them, how about performance?