# How to get sentences from a paragraph with custom list of words in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to read a paragraph and capture all the sentences in it with words matching a dynamic list of words.

The python pre-processing steps will identify the list of words. 
I want to use this list of words and identify sentences in the paragraph that has at least one of the words from the list. All those identified sentences will be appended to a new variable.

Input: "Machine learning is the science of getting computers to act without being explicitly programmed. Machine learning is so pervasive today that you probably use it dozens of times a day without knowing it. Many researchers also think it is the best way to make progress towards human-level AI."

list of words: computer, researcher

Output: Machine learning is the science of getting computers to act without being explicitly programmed.Many researchers also think it is the best way to make progress towards human-level AI.

What is the best way to accomplish this ?

Comment: What is your way to accomplish this? Please show your attempt

Comment: In future it is best to provide an example of what you have tried so we understand more about what you want - it also shows that you don't simply want us to do your work for you.

Comment: The point of the exercise is to improve yourself, you're missing out if you get someone else to do the thinking for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based partially on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576110/2202669):

```
import nltk

tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
text = "Machine learning is the science of getting computers to act without being explicitly programmed. Machine learning is so pervasive today that you probably use it dozens of times a day without knowing it. Many researchers also think it is the best way to make progress towards human-level AI."
word_list = ['computer', 'researcher']
output_list = []

for sentence in tokenizer.tokenize(text):
    for word in word_list:
        if word in sentence:
            output_list.append(sentence)
            break # useful when word_list is large
```

You need to run `nltk.download()` beforehand and download `punkt` in the `Models` tab.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was already using nltk and tokenizer in previous steps but didn't know there was a sentence function.Thanks fenceop!

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to his,

```
lst = ['computer', 'researcher']
''.join(re.findall(r'[^.]*(?:' + '|'.join(lst) + r')[^.]*\.', sen))
```

This would fail if decimal numbers present. If you also want to deal with those, then try this,

```
''.join(re.findall(r'(?:\d.\d|[^.])*(?:' + '|'.join(lst) + r')(?:\d\.\d|[^.])*\.', s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex for non regular patterns, they are difficult to understand, often verbose and inefficient.

What you want can easily be done with the following:

```
x = "Machine learning is the science of getting computers to act without being explicitly programmed. Machine learning is so pervasive today that you probably use it dozens of times a day without knowing it. Many researchers also think it is the best way to make progress towards human-level AI."

l = ['computer', 'researcher']

for line in x.split('.'):
    for word in l:
        if word in line:
            print(line)
            break
```

output:

```
Machine learning is the science of getting computers to act without being explicitly programmed
 Many researchers also think it is the best way to make progress towards human-level AI
```