# Looking for a Django template filter like truncatewords that truncates on a sentence boundary

Tags: python, regex, django

I’m looking for a template tag something like [truncatewords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords) that will truncate a string (usually: `TextField`s) on a sentence boundary (double newline, sentence punctuation etc.).

I’d prefer to implement this as a template tag for maximum portability. I would use it on several projects where I can’t alter `models.py`.

I realize this probably involves Regular Expressions which…wow, where to start? I’m a designer & not much of a programmer.

This seems like a really common problem and surely someone has some traction on it elsewhere.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it could be as easy as splitting the text field by sentence complete signs, then take the number of sentences you want. It's very easy to code up a template filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters. You need to search for a good way to split text into sentences though.

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty confident writing template filters—it's the “search for a good way to split text into sentences” part I need help with.

Comment: Splitting text into sentences is a very complex topic that involves natural language processing and semantic analysis. I don't believe that django has this,  but as you might already googled, use `Natural Language Toolkit` for it should be the easiest way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/python-split-text-on-sentences.