# Print sentences from text file that starts and ends with particular words or character?

Tags: python

How to find sentences in text file that starts and ends with particular words for example sentences that starts with 'The' and ends with 'u'.I have tried

```
def main():
  f=open('D:\\file.txt')
  print 'The lines that starts with The and Ends with u'
  for line in f:
     for j in line.split('.'):
         if j[0]=='T' and j[1]=='h' and j[2]=='e' and j[3]==' ' and  j[-1]=='u':
            print j
if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

Instead of character comparison can we do this using word comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) to do the comparison with strings:

```
print 'The lines that starts with The and Ends with u'

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('The') and line.endswith('u'):
            print line
```

Comment: Sentences normally end with some kind of punctuation, not a letter :)

Comment: True but given that there's no example input and the given code prints message about lines one has to make some assumptions. Anyway the main point, using `startswith` and `endswith` will solve the problem as long as sentences/lines are properly read & constructed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few easy ways to read "sentences" and a couple more sophisticated ones (but they are a lot better — e.g. NLTK).
Pick your favourite from this question: [Python split text on sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/python-split-text-on-sentences)

After you are done with extracting "sentences" instead of lines, you can pretty much use your own code for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

x = 'The lines that starts with The and Ends with u'

print(re.findall(r'\A(The)\s(\w+\s)+u\Z',x))
```

Comment: It is good to explain what this does. Answers like yours are automatically put among Low Quality Posts and people have to decide if they are to be deleted.

Comment: Ok! I didn't know that. Thank you for letting me know. 

Explanation:
I have tried finding out the requirements using regex. So, I have imported the re module to use regex and then the expression, \A- represents check for the presence at the start of the string and \s is the space that is followed after the first word.(\w+\s) implies there can be a series of literals followed by space,and + is used to say match atleast 1 or more and finally u\Z,where\Z implies look for 'u' at the end of the string.