# How to count sentences taking into account the occurrence of ellipses

Tags: python, regex

I've written the following script to count the number of sentences in a text file:

```
import re

filepath = 'sample_text_with_ellipsis.txt'

with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.read()

sentences = re.split(r'[.{1}!?]+', read_data.replace('\n',''))
sentences = sentences[:-1]
sentence_count = len(sentences)
```

However, if I run it on a `sample_text_with_ellipsis.txt` with the following content:

```
Wait for it... awesome!
```

I get `sentence_count = 2` instead of `1`, because it does not ignore the ellipsis (i.e., the "...").

What I tried to do in the regex is to make it match only one occurrence of a period through `.{1}`, but this apparently doesn't work the way I intended it. How can I get the regex to ignore ellipses?

Comment: Is `Wait for it... Awesome!` to be considered one sentence or two?

Comment: `re.split(r'(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)|[!?]', str)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Splitting sentences with a regex like this is not enough. See [*Python split text on sentences*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/python-split-text-on-sentences)  to see how NLTK can be leveraged for this.

Answering your question, you call 3 dot sequence an ellipsis. Thus, you need to use

```
[!?]+|(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iW1eV2/2). The `.` is moved from the character class since **you can't use quantifiers inside them**, and only that `.` is matched that is not enclosed with other dots.

- `[!?]+` - 1 or more `!` or `?`
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)` - a dot that is neither preceded (`(?<!\.)`), nor followed (`(?!\.)`) with a dot.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/k0sqWV):

```
import re
sentences = re.split(r'[!?]+|(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)', "Wait for it... awesome!".replace('\n',''))
sentences = sentences[:-1]
sentence_count = len(sentences)
print(sentence_count)  # => 1
```

Comment: Hello, how do you do when you have a sentence that contains 'number.number' and you don't want to cut it ?

Comment: @jos97 This is an old answer, now, I'd use spacy. To avoid matching a dot between two digits, you can use `\.(?!(?<=\d.)\d)`. So, the pattern above will turn into `r'[!?]+|(?<!\.)\.(?!(?<=\d.)\d)(?!\.)'`

Answer (score 0):

Following Wiktor's suggestion to use NLTK, I also came up with the following alternative solution:

```
import nltk
read_data="Wait for it... awesome!"
sentence_count = len(nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(read_data))
```

This yields a sentence count of 1 as expected.