# How to split text into subsentence with python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to split a text into subsentence. How can I do that?

For example:

```
text = "Hi, this is an apple. Hi, that is pineapple."
```

The result should be:

```
['Hi,',
 'this is an apple.',
 'Hi,',
 'that is pineapple.']
```

(P.S. I tried with the `string.split(r'[,.]')`, but it will remove the separators.)

Comment: So you just want to split by any punctuation?

Comment: @chris I think, it should be an "," in addition to sentence tokenizer

Comment: What about an array of arrays where each sentence is broken down into its tokens?

Comment: @chris what means an array of arrays? can you give me a detailed example?

Comment: Per your example: `[['Hi,',
 'this is an apple.'],
 ['Hi,',
 'that is pineapple.']]` I am not saying there is anything at all wrong with what you are trying to do, just suggesting something that would allow you to keep track of sentences as well as tokens within each of those sentences.

Comment: @chris I think, it is also ok. The most important is I want to keep the "," and "."

Comment: OK.  If you wanted to do that you can just do `[h.split(',') for h in text.split('.') if h != '']` otherwise the given answers will help you!

Comment: @chris, thanks, I think, this is also a good way to keep track of sentences. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split on whitespace `\s+` with [a zero-length look-behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=[,.])` for the punctuation.

```
import re

text = "Hi, this is an apple. Hi, that is pineapple."
subsentence = re.compile(r'(?<=[,.])\s+')

print(subsentence.split(text))
```

`['Hi,', 'this is an apple.', 'Hi,', 'that is pineapple.']`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this could work too:

```
text.replace(', ', ',, ').replace('. ', '., ').split(', ')
```

Results in:

```
['Hi,', 'this is an apple.', 'Hi,', 'that is pineapple.']
```

Comment: This solution is so simple and beautiful!

Comment: @FatihAkici Yeah, a little hack. But I think the accepted answer is more effective. :)

Comment: I agree! It is the proper way but this hack is more beautiful :)

Answer (score 3):

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/python-split-text-on-sentences)

The [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/) provides a tokenizer that you can use to split sentences. For example:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()   # enter "punkt"

>>> import nltk.data
>>> tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
>>> data = "Hi, this is an apple. Hi, that is pineapple."
>>> data = data.replace(',', '.')
>>> tokenizer.tokenize(data)
['Hi.', 'this is an apple.', 'Hi.', 'that is pineapple.']
```

Details of the tokenizer are [documented here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html).

Comment: this will split the text into two sentences. But, I wish, it split into 4 parts, also with ","

Comment: Ah. Could you replace commas with periods, then use the tokenizer?

Comment: Do you mean the similiar way like @Anton vBR suggested?

Comment: Updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution using [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import re

text = "Hi, this is an apple. Hi, that is pineapple."

punct_locs = [0] + [i.start() + 1 for i in re.finditer(r'[,.]', text)]

sentences = [text[start:end].strip() for start, end in zip(punct_locs[:-1], punct_locs[1:])]

print(sentences)
```

Which outputs:

```
['Hi,', 'this is an apple.', 'Hi,', 'that is pineapple.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are making it too much complex by importing heavy modules , just go with simple and clean method without importing any module :

```
text = "Hi, this is an apple. Hi, that is pineapple."
for i in text.split('.'):
    if i:
        print(i.strip().split(','))
```

output:

```
['Hi', ' this is an apple']
['Hi', ' that is pineapple']
```

> You can do in one line :

```
text = "Hi, this is an apple. Hi, that is pineapple."
print([i.strip().split(',') for i in text.split('.') if i])
```

output:

```
[['Hi', ' this is an apple'], ['Hi', ' that is pineapple']]
```