# In Python, how can I identify and replace numeric values at the start of each sentence?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

**Objective:** to find digits that start at the beginning of a sentence and change the number in place to equal the original number plus 10%.

```
msg_orginal = """Hello, I am new here. 
2,431 other coders are new here too. 
Imagine if 2.5 were not new here? 
2,428.5 would then be new."""
```

The output I am seeking is as follows:

```
msg_revised = """Hello, I am new here. 
2,674.1 other coders are new here too. 
Imagine if 2.5 were not new here? 
2,671.35 would then be new."""
```

Notice how two of the three sentences have changed the numerical values, but one did not.

**EDIT:**
Keep in mind the same number could appear multiple times in the string. And a new sentence is a sentence that comes either after a full stop (such as a period, exclamation mark, question mark) or that comes after a new line character.

Comment: @jdehesa Actually, using regex may be easier

Comment: @Student Is it possible that the same number will appear twice?

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes. I have added clarification to the above. Thank you for asking the question.

Comment: A new sentence is a sentence that comes after a full stop (or a question mark etc..) or that comes after a new line character?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a regex like `r"^[\d,.]+"` using the multiline-flag `re.M` so that `^` matches a line break and a replacement function for doing the math and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1823058/1639625) the output:

```
>>> increase = lambda m: "{:,.2f}".format(float(m.group().replace(",","")) * 1.1)

>>> print(re.sub(r"^[\d,.]+", increase, msg_orginal, flags=re.M))
Hello, I am new here. 
2,674.10 other coders are new here too. 
Imagine if 2.5 were not new here? 
2,671.35 would then be new.
```

This assumes that all sentences start at a new line (and no sentences span more than one line) as is the case in your example. This problems (if itis a problem) can be handled [separately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576077/1639625).

Answer (score 0):

```
msg_orginal = """Hello, I am new here. 
2,431 other coders are new here too. 
Imagine if 2.5 were not new here? 
2,428.5 would then be new."""

res = []

for i in msg_orginal.split("\n"):
    if i[0].isdigit():
        val = i.split()
        f = float(val[0].replace(",", ""))
        val[0] = str((f/10.0) + f)
        res.append(" ".join(val))
    else:
        res.append(i)

print "\n".join(res)
```

**Output:**

```
Hello, I am new here. 
2674.1 other coders are new here too.
Imagine if 2.5 were not new here? 
2671.35 would then be new.
```