# How to capitalize the beginning of each sentence with python?

Tags: python, arrays

What I'm trying to do is to get some text from the user store it in a variable. I then split that variable by a period which gives me a sentence_list. Then I want to capitalize the starting word of each element contained in the list.

`userText = input('Enter your text: ')
sentence = userText.split('. ')`

Comment: "I then split that variable by a period which gives me a sentence_list." Are you sure of that? Related: [Python split text on sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576077/1639625)

Comment: `>>> 'i am a robot'.title()` produces `'I Am A Robot'`. `>>> 'i am a robot'.capitalize()` produces `'I am a robot.'`. Beep bop.

Comment: To capitalize the first character of strings in a list: `cap_list = [x[0].upper() + x[1:] for x in sentence]`. You may want to call `strip()` on it to strip whitespace.

Comment: @whp Don't actually do that. Python has a built-in tool for that already. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If you want to capitalize the first letter in each str, use `capitalize`. To capitalize the first letter in each word, use `title`. Read Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize).

Comment: @whp, EDIT: it works!

Comment: @GOD - sentence should be a list of sentences (same as the variable `sentence` in your post), not a string. Also, use `capitalize` as it was pointed out. `[x.capitalize() for x in sentence]`

Comment: @GOD, no it does not. `title()` does capitalize every word in the string, `capitalize()` only capitalizes the first word and only if it begins with alphabetical character.