# What is the simplest way to capitalize the first word in a sentence for multiple sentences in python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my homework I have tried to get the first word of each sentence to capitalize.

This is for python 3.7.

```py
def fix_cap():
    if "." in initialInput:
        sentsplit = initialInput.split(". ")
        capsent = [x.capitalize() for x in sentsplit]
        joinsent = ". ".join(capsent)
        print("Number of words capitalized: " + str(len(sentsplit)))
        print("Edited text: " + joinsent)
    elif "!" in initialInput:
        sentsplit = initialInput.split("! ")
        capsent = [x.capitalize() for x in sentsplit]
        joinsent = "! ".join(capsent)
        print("Number of words capitalized: " + str(len(sentsplit)))
        print("Edited text: " + joinsent)
    elif "?" in initialInput:
        sentsplit = initialInput.split("? ")
        capsent = [x.capitalize() for x in sentsplit]
        joinsent = "? ".join(capsent)
        print("Number of words capitalized: " + str(len(sentsplit)))
        print("Edited text: " + joinsent)
    else:
        print(initialInput.capitalize())
```

This will work if only one type of punctuation is used, but I would like it to work with multiple types in a paragraph.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576077/1639625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correctly splitting a text into sentences is *hard*. For how to do this correctly also for cases like e.g. abbreviations, names with titles etc., please refer to other questions on this site, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/python-split-text-on-sentences). This is only a very simple version, based on your conditions, which, I assume, will suffice for your task.

As you noticed, your code only works for one type of punctuation, because of the `if/elif/else` construct. But you do not need that at all! If e.g. there is no `?` in the text, then `split("? ")` will just return the text as a whole (wrapped in a list). You could just remove the conditions, or iterate a list of possible sentence-ending punctuation. However, note that `capitalize` will not just upper-case the first letter, but also lower-case all the rest, e.g. names, acronyms, or words previously capitalized for a different type of punctuation. Instead, you could just `upper` the first char and keep the rest.

```
text = "text with. multiple types? of sentences! more stuff."
for sep in (". ", "? ", "! "):
    text = sep.join(s[0].upper() + s[1:] for s in text.split(sep))
print(text)
# Text with. Multiple types? Of sentences! More stuff.
```

You could also use a regular expression to split by *all* sentence separators at once. This way, you might even be ablt to use `capitalize`, although it will still lower-case names and acronyms.

```
import re
>>> ''.join(s.capitalize() for s in re.split(r"([\?\!\.] )", text))
'Text with. Multiple types? Of sentences! More stuff.'
```

Or using `re.sub` with a look-behind (note the first char is still lower-case):

```
>>> re.sub(r"(?<=[\?\!\.] ).", lambda m: m.group().upper(), text)
'text with. Multiple types? Of sentences! More stuff.'
```

However, unless you know what those are doing, I'd suggest going with the first loop-based version.