# Avoid author name from splitting Python

Tags: python, split, pdf-reader

I'm reading a PDF file and split whole text on the base of delimiter ('**.**') but that PDF also contains author names like this;

> Similar to the work of Valenzuela et al. [1] and Zhu et al. [2], we use features like citations from citing to cited paper, citations per section, and author overlap.

and my code split this one line into 3 like this

- Similar to the work of Valenzuela et al
- [1] and Zhu et al
- [2], we use features like citations from citing to cited paper,
  citations per section, and author overlap

Here is my code to read pdf text and split it;

```
from tika import parser
import re

rege x = re.compile(r'\[\d]')

objFile = parser.from_file('read.pdf')
text = objFile['content']
lstString = text.strip()
lstString = lstString.split(".")
```

Can anyone help me how can I avoid author name from splitting?

Comment: Can I ask you a hypothetical question? What if the authors name was `J. R. R. Tolkien`?

Comment: Generally you can use the "split" function of the "re" module with an appropriate regular expression which can exclude some abbreviations e. g. by look-behind matches. But it will be hard to develop rules to dinguish sentence end from abbreviation reliably.

Comment: @user1558604 exactly.. it would be disaster

Comment: Would this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/python-split-text-on-sentences

Comment: nope..it is doing exactly same..