# Split sentences in python with citations

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I'm trying to split sentences from academic papers. Traditionally splitting sentences would simply be:

```
sentence = 'This is a sentence. This is another sentence'
separate = sentence.split('.')

#  [ This is a sentence, This is another sentence ]
```

However, this logic does not work if you have sentences such as:

```
This is a sentence is a paper with a citation (author et al., 2020a) and it contains more 
information. This is similar to the examples I have (author et al., 2020a).
```

How could I split sentences (like the sample above) so the output would look something like this:

```
['This is a sentence is a paper with a citation (author et al., 2020a) and it contains more information' , 'This is similar to the examples I have (author et al., 2020a)' ]
```

What is an easy solution to this problem? Appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: How about nltk package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to split on `"\. (?>[A-Z])"` (dot space uppercase) :

```
sentences = values.split(r"\. (?>[A-Z])") # split nicely in the 2 sentences
sentences = values.split(r"\. ") # more basic and generic
```

A more powerful one is to use a dedicated lib like `nltk` : [Python split text on sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/python-split-text-on-sentences)

Comment: Your first solution before you edited actually worked better in my case!

Comment: The regex will fail on something simple like `Mr. Walker is running.`, or any other abbreviation followed by a name.