# How to split a text into sentences while keeping the punctuations?

Tags: python-3.x, string, split

guys. I am a novice at Python 3.8. I need to split a text into sentences while keeping the punctuations. You can also encounter countinuous punctuations. I haven't learnt regular expression so is there a way using simple codes like find() and slicing strings to do this? I tried find() and slices but it is not a one-size-fits-all code. Looking forward to better ways of using find() and slice. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I split a text into sentences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/how-can-i-split-a-text-into-sentences)

Comment: No, but thanks.:)  I have already handed in my homework. Waiting for our teacher's feedback. Maybe this will be easier for me after learning regular expression. Thanks a loooooooot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split('. ')` to split the string into several list elements which are split by `.`

And in order to maintain the same punctuations append `.`  to all list element.

```
>>> text = "guys. I am a novice at Python 3.8. I need to split a text into sentences while keeping the punctuations. You can also encounter countinuous punctuations. I haven't learnt regular expression so is there a way using simple codes like find() and slicing strings to do this? I tried find() and slices but it is not a one-size-fits-all code. Looking forward to better ways of using find() and slice. Thanks."
>>> sentences = [f'{i}. ' for i in text.split('. ')]
>>> sentences
['guys. ', 'I am a novice at Python 3.8. ', 'I need to split a text into sentences while keeping the punctuations. ', 'You can also encounter countinuous punctuations. ', "I haven't learnt regular expression so is there a way using simple codes like find() and slicing strings to do this? I tried find() and slices but it is not a one-size-fits-all code. ", 'Looking forward to better ways of using find() and slice. ', 'Thanks.. ']
```

Comment: Yup, yeah, this works. It isn't great for large blocks of text. +1

Comment: :) Many thanks! I should have refreshed this page earlier. But if puncts =  set('；。！…？') , these kinds of punctuations at the end of a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large block of text, you will likely want to use an `generator` so that you are not copying a bunch of times.

## For example:

```
import re

paragraph = """
This is a sentence. This may be another one. I am not sure.
"""

sentence_regex = r'[^.]+.'
# match one or more not periods, followed by a period


def find_sentences(text):
    for match in re.finditer(sentence_regex, text):
        yield match.group(0).strip()


for sentence in find_sentences(paragraph):
    print(sentence)
```

## Execution:

```
[ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ python sentence.py 
This is a sentence.
This may be another one.
I am not sure.
```

Comment: Yep, this is where the problem lies. We are gonna learn RE next class. T T but thanks a lot! You made my day.