# How to split text into sentences by including corner cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, nlp, python-re

I am using this link for splitting text into sentences:

[How can I split a text into sentences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/how-can-i-split-a-text-into-sentences).

Here is the code:

```
%%time
import re
alphabets= "([A-Za-z])"
prefixes = "(Mr|St|Mrs|Ms|Dr)[.]"
suffixes = "(Inc|Ltd|Jr|Sr|Co)"
starters = "(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|He\s|She\s|It\s|They\s|Their\s|Our\s|We\s|But\s|However\s|That\s|This\s|Wherever)"
acronyms = "([A-Z][.][A-Z][.](?:[A-Z][.])?)"
websites = "[.](com|net|org|io|gov|ly)"
digits = "([0-9])"


def split_into_sentences(text):
    text = " " + text + "  "
    text = text.replace("\n"," ")
    text = re.sub(prefixes,"\\1<prd>",text)
    text = re.sub(websites,"<prd>\\1",text)
    text = re.sub(digits + "[.]" + digits,"\\1<prd>\\2",text)
    
    if "Ph.D" in text: text = text.replace("Ph.D.","Ph<prd>D<prd>")
        
    text = re.sub("\s" + alphabets + "[.] "," \\1<prd> ",text)
    text = re.sub(acronyms+" "+starters,"\\1<stop> \\2",text)
    text = re.sub(alphabets + "[.]" + alphabets + "[.]" + alphabets + "[.]","\\1<prd>\\2<prd>\\3<prd>",text)
    text = re.sub(alphabets + "[.]" + alphabets + "[.]","\\1<prd>\\2<prd>",text)
    text = re.sub(" "+suffixes+"[.] "+starters," \\1<stop> \\2",text)
    text = re.sub(" "+suffixes+"[.]"," \\1<prd>",text)
    text = re.sub(" " + alphabets + "[.]"," \\1<prd>",text)
    if "”" in text: text = text.replace(".”","”.")
    if "\"" in text: text = text.replace(".\"","\".")
    if "!" in text: text = text.replace("!\"","\"!")
    if "?" in text: text = text.replace("?\"","\"?")
    text = text.replace(".",".<stop>")
    text = text.replace("?","?<stop>")
    text = text.replace("!","!<stop>")
    text = text.replace("<prd>",".")
    sentences = text.split("<stop>")
    sentences = sentences[:-1]
    sentences = [s.strip() for s in sentences]
    
    if len(sentences)==0:
        k=[]
        return [text]
    else:
        return sentences
```

Though the above code works well for most of the corner cases. But if failed in few cases like:

`text="Thank you for contacting back. Request you to please help us with the transaction ID for $<***>.92 ? - Charlie."`

It breaks the `$<***>.92` into `$<***>.` and `92`. How can I include this in above code?

Comment: Use the NLTK library or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to extend your code, you can add the dollar sign (`$`) to the floating value parsing:

```
text = re.sub("$" + digits + "[.]" + digits,"\\1<prd>\\2",text)
```