# How to show first 2-3 sentences of some content in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a post object which has content attribute which is basically a TextField. I want to show first few sentences (not words, I want it to truncate after 2-3 full stops, or something like that) as preview of post on my webpage.

{{ post.content }}

How do I do that in my template?

Comment: Look up Django template tags and filters filters that should do exactly what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to split the given text into sentences, you can use the function provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31505798/11544538)

Next, register your custom template tag that uses the above function, and here you go:

```py
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

from <your utils package> import split_into_sentences

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def truncate_sentences(value, length=3):
    sentences = split_into_sentences(value)
    return ' '.join(sentences[:length])
```

Then simply use the custom template tag in your template:

```
{{ post.content|truncate_sentences:3 }}
```