# Search for a string in .txt file, print whole sentence (everything before string, till '.' /fullstop sign/ and everything after string, till '.' sign)

Tags: python-3.x, string, full-text-search

This is my code, it currently prints the whole line, that contains the string. I want to print the whole sentence, that contains the searchString.

```
searchString = 'doctorate'
files = os.listdir() # goes directory with *.txt files
for eachFile in files:
    with open(eachFile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as currentFile:
        allLines = currentFile.readlines()
        for line in allLines:
            if searchString in line:
                print (line)
```

Any help will be apreciated...

Comment: `read()` the whole document as a single string then split on `'.'`. You might also need to handle `'?'` and `'!`' and periods in the middle of sentences.

Comment: [How can I split a text into sentences?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576077)

Comment: Okay... I got some trouble

fullText = currentFile.read()
for searchString in fullText:
        if searchString in fullText:
            sentence = [ here I don't know how to proceed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple, naïve approach to split the text into sentences:

```
import re

search = "doctorate"
with open(path_to_your_file, 'r') as file:
    text = file.read().replace('\n', ' ')
    sentences = re.split(r"([\.!?])\s+", text)
    for index,sentence in enumerate(sentences):
        if search in sentence.lower():
            print(sentence + sentences[index+1])
```

However, if your text is more complex, you will need more advanced parsing.