# best way to split strings such that they create additional rows in the data set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I want to run a pretrained NLP model on the data set that contains lots of reviews. Some reviews are extremely long, such way I receive the error:

> the expanded size of the tensor (1164) must match the existing size (512) at non-singleton dimension 1. target sizes: [1, 1164]. tensor sizes: [1, 512]

I do not want to delete the reviews and maximising tokenizer.model_max_length = 10000 did not work, so I want to split the reviews in several parts.

The existing dataset looks like this:

| review id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 33435 | This is such an amazing product! I would<...> And that's how I met your mother |
| <...> | <...> |

I want to get this:

| review id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 33435 | This is such an amazing product! |
| 33435 | I would defninitely buy it again and again |
| 33435 | When first time I bought it I decided that I will do it all my life |

This way I separate every each 450 symbols from each other and putting them into separate row.
How can I do that?

Comment: From the error I can see that you are probably using transformers. These models have 512 token limit. Hence, the error.

Comment: You also need to show what you have tried so the community can help you on specific examples.

Comment: This could help: to [split texts into sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576077/14627505)

Answer (score 0):

**I bet there's some third party Python package that does exactly what you're looking for. I recommend you try googling it before using my suggestion.**

Anyway, the following code might work for most cases:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Iterable
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Setting max_colwidth to None, to force pandas not to truncate the "text" column.
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)


def process_review(
    review_text: str,
    split_len: int = 40,
    separators: list[str] | None = None,
):
    """Split a review into multiple sentences.

    Parameters
    ----------
    review_text : str
        The review text.
    split_len : int, default=40
        The maximum length of each sentence
    separators : list[str] | None, optional
        The separators to split the review, by default None

    Returns
    -------
    list[str]
        The list of sentences.

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        If `separators` is not a string, or iterable.
    """
    if separators is None:
        separators = ['.', ';', '?', '!', '...', '\n']
    elif isinstance(separators, str):
        separators = [separators]
    elif not isinstance(separators, Iterable):
        raise ValueError(f'`separators` {separators} not Iterable.')

    for sep in separators:
        review_text = review_text.replace(sep, '.')

    # This is to account for strings like: "!?", "!!", "??", etc.
    # Remove this while/loop if you don't want to modify these types of punctuation
    # to single full stop punctuation (".").
    while '..' in review_text:
        review_text = review_text.replace('..', '.')

    review_len = len(review_text)
    if review_len <= split_len:
        return review_text
    
    lines = []
    line = ''
    for sentence in (s.strip() + '.' for s in review_text.split('.')[:-1]):
        # can't fit on that line => start new one
        if len(line) + len(sentence) + 1 >= split_len:
            lines.append(line)
            line = sentence
        # can fit on => add a space then this sentence
        else:
            line += ' ' if line != '' else '' + sentence      
    lines.append(line)
    return lines


def extend_iloc(df: pd.DataFrame, col_target: str = 'text') -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Replicate rows of a DataFrame and add a flattened column of lists.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pd.DataFrame
        DataFrame with a column of lists.
    col_target : str, optional
        Name of the column of lists, by default 'text'.

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame
        DataFrame with replicated rows and a flattened column of lists.
    """
    # Flatten columns of lists
    col_flat = [item for sublist in df[col_target] for item in sublist]

    # Row numbers to repeat 
    lens = df[col_target].apply(len)
    vals = range(df.shape[0])
    ilocations = np.repeat(vals, lens)
    
    # Replicate rows and add flattened column of lists
    cols = [i for i, c in enumerate(df.columns) if c != col_target]
    new_df = df.iloc[ilocations, cols].copy()
    new_df[col_target] = col_flat
    return new_df


# Creating example dataframe
original_reviews = pd.DataFrame(
    {'review id': ['33435', '33436'],
     'text': ['This is such an amazing product! I would defninitely buy it again '
              'and again. When first time I bought it, I decided that I will do it all my life.',
             'This is such an amazing product!!! I would defninitely buy it again '
              'and again. When first time I bought it, I decided that I will do it all my life.']})


# Splitting 'text' column rows into list of smaller sentences.
original_reviews['text'] = original_reviews['text'].apply(process_review)

# Note: You can control the maximum lenght of each sentence, by setting a custom value
#       for the `split_len` parameter. By default it's set to 40.
# original_reviews['text'] = original_reviews['text'].apply(process_review, split_len=60)

# Transforming each value from lists into separate rows.
print(extend_iloc(original_reviews))
# Prints:
# 
#   review id                                                                     text
# 0     33435                                         This is such an amazing product. 
# 0     33435                              I would defninitely buy it again and again. 
# 0     33435    When first time I bought it, I decided that I will do it all my life. 
# 1     33436                                         This is such an amazing product. 
# 1     33436                              I would defninitely buy it again and again. 
# 1     33436    When first time I bought it, I decided that I will do it all my life.
```

I'm sure this implementation won't work for all situations. Specially for large sentences, without many breaks. Unfortunately, there are too many corner-cases when it comes to a use-case like the one you're trying yo solve.