# Programmatically install NLTK corpora / models, i.e. without the GUI downloader?

Tags: installation, package, nltk, requirements, corpus

My project uses the NLTK. How can I list the project's corpus & model requirements so they can be automatically installed? I don't want to click through the `nltk.download()` GUI, installing packages one by one.

Also, any way to freeze that same list of requirements (like `pip freeze`)?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The NLTK site does list a command line interface for downloading packages and collections at the bottom of this page :

http://www.nltk.org/data

The command line usage varies by which version of Python you are using, but on my Python2.6 install I noticed I was missing the 'spanish_grammar' model and this worked fine:

```
python -m nltk.downloader spanish_grammars
```

You mention listing the project's corpus and model requirements and while I'm not sure of a way to automagically do that, I figured I would at least share this.

Answer (score 31):

To install all NLTK corpora & models:

```
python -m nltk.downloader all
```

Alternatively, on Linux, you can use:

```
sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data all
```

Replace `all` by `popular` if you just want to list the most popular corpora & models.

---

You may also browse the corpora & models through the command line:

```
mlee@server:/scratch/jjylee/tests$ sudo python -m nltk.downloader
[sudo] password for jjylee:
NLTK Downloader
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloader> d

Download which package (l=list; x=cancel)?
  Identifier> l
Packages:
  [ ] averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru Averaged Perceptron Tagger (Russian)
  [ ] basque_grammars..... Grammars for Basque
  [ ] bllip_wsj_no_aux.... BLLIP Parser: WSJ Model
  [ ] book_grammars....... Grammars from NLTK Book
  [ ] cess_esp............ CESS-ESP Treebank
  [ ] chat80.............. Chat-80 Data Files
  [ ] city_database....... City Database
  [ ] cmudict............. The Carnegie Mellon Pronouncing Dictionary (0.6)
  [ ] comparative_sentences Comparative Sentence Dataset
  [ ] comtrans............ ComTrans Corpus Sample
  [ ] conll2000........... CONLL 2000 Chunking Corpus
  [ ] conll2002........... CONLL 2002 Named Entity Recognition Corpus
  [ ] conll2007........... Dependency Treebanks from CoNLL 2007 (Catalan
                           and Basque Subset)
  [ ] crubadan............ Crubadan Corpus
  [ ] dependency_treebank. Dependency Parsed Treebank
  [ ] europarl_raw........ Sample European Parliament Proceedings Parallel
                           Corpus
  [ ] floresta............ Portuguese Treebank
  [ ] framenet_v15........ FrameNet 1.5
Hit Enter to continue: 
  [ ] framenet_v17........ FrameNet 1.7
  [ ] gazetteers.......... Gazeteer Lists
  [ ] genesis............. Genesis Corpus
  [ ] gutenberg........... Project Gutenberg Selections
  [ ] hmm_treebank_pos_tagger Treebank Part of Speech Tagger (HMM)
  [ ] ieer................ NIST IE-ER DATA SAMPLE
  [ ] inaugural........... C-Span Inaugural Address Corpus
  [ ] indian.............. Indian Language POS-Tagged Corpus
  [ ] jeita............... JEITA Public Morphologically Tagged Corpus (in
                           ChaSen format)
  [ ] kimmo............... PC-KIMMO Data Files
  [ ] knbc................ KNB Corpus (Annotated blog corpus)
  [ ] large_grammars...... Large context-free and feature-based grammars
                           for parser comparison
  [ ] lin_thesaurus....... Lin's Dependency Thesaurus
  [ ] mac_morpho.......... MAC-MORPHO: Brazilian Portuguese news text with
                           part-of-speech tags
  [ ] machado............. Machado de Assis -- Obra Completa
  [ ] masc_tagged......... MASC Tagged Corpus
  [ ] maxent_ne_chunker... ACE Named Entity Chunker (Maximum entropy)
  [ ] moses_sample........ Moses Sample Models
Hit Enter to continue: x


Download which package (l=list; x=cancel)?
  Identifier> conll2002
    Downloading package conll2002 to
        /afs/mit.edu/u/m/mlee/nltk_data...
      Unzipping corpora/conll2002.zip.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloader>
```

Answer (score 19):

In addition to the command line option already mentioned, you can programmatically install NLTK data in your Python script by adding an argument to the `download()` function.

See the `help(nltk.download)` text, specifically:

> ```
> Individual packages can be downloaded by calling the ``download()``
> function with a single argument, giving the package identifier for the
> package that should be downloaded:
>
>     >>> download('treebank') # doctest: +SKIP
>     [nltk_data] Downloading package 'treebank'...
>     [nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora/treebank.zip.
> ```

I can confirm that this works for downloading one package at a time, or when passed a `list` or `tuple`.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('wordnet')
[nltk_data] Downloading package 'wordnet' to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\_my-username_\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora\wordnet.zip.
True
```

You may also try to download an already downloaded package without problems:

```
>>> nltk.download('wordnet')
[nltk_data] Downloading package 'wordnet' to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\_my-username_\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package wordnet is already up-to-date!
True
```

Also, it appears the function returns a boolean value that you can use to see whether or not the download succeeded:

```
>>> nltk.download('not-a-real-name')
[nltk_data] Error loading not-a-real-name: Package 'not-a-real-name'
[nltk_data]     not found in index
False
```

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to install the corpora and models inside a custom directory using the following code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download(info_or_id="popular", download_dir="/path/to/dir")
nltk.data.path.append("/path/to/dir")
```

this will install "**all**" corpora/models inside `/path/to/dir`, and will let know NLTK where to look for it (`data.path.append`).

You can't «freeze» the data in a requirements file, but you could add this code to your `__init__` besides come code to check if the files are already there.