# Python Package with NLTK as a Dependency

Tags: python, parsing, nltk

I've looked around for a question pertaining to this without any hits, so here we go:

I am working on a toy python package to deploy on PyPi.org. A part of its job involves streamlining the process of parsing text and generating tokenized sentences. Naturally, I have considered using `nltk` for the job, having personally used tools like `punkt` from the package.

Here's the problem and my question: Having looked at the size of `nltk` and the requirements for it to work, with the corpora nearly **10 gigabytes** in size, I've come to the conclusion this is an outlandish burden to put on anyone who wants to use my package given its use-case.

Is there anyway to deploy a "pre-trained" instance of `punkt`? Or can I control the size of the corpora used by `nltk`?

I am equally open to an alternative package/solution for parsing relatively "sane" human text that is somewhat close to performance of `nltk` but without the same disk memory footprint.

Thanks for any help.

---

solution as indicated below by @matisetorm for me is:

```
python -m nltk.downloader punkt
```

Comment: You can selectively download corpora like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843817/programmatically-install-nltk-corpora-models-i-e-without-the-gui-downloader) or using the [GUI](http://www.nltk.org/data.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.

1) You can selectively download corpora like described at [Programmatically install NLTK corpora / models, i.e. without the GUI downloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843817/programmatically-install-nltk-corpora-models-i-e-without-the-gui-downloader) For example,

`python -m nltk.downloader <your package you would like to download>`

2) or using the GUI with instructions at http://www.nltk.org/data.html

Which basically amounts to doing the following and command line

```
python3
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

Comment: Your answer and Patrick's point to the same solution. I'd like to add the knowledge I found in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275001/use-of-punktsentencetokenizer-in-nltk) which seems to indicate that `punkt` itself comes with pre-trained models. Limiting myself to `punkt` puts the memory footprint at only ~50mb, much more reasonable.

Comment: but of course. :) you should always limit yourself to only those data libraries you need. See option 1. punkt is a pretty awesome resource. There have been times I just download the one I need and put it into my repository directly