# Not able to download nltk.download() in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter-notebook, nltk, corpus

I am trying to download the whole text book but its just showing kernel busy. I left it for half an hour but still showing in busy state. When I stopped it, below error came. Can anyone guide me how to fix the issue or am I not following the steps properly.

---

```
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-fec50ed38a60> in <module>()
      1 import nltk
----> 2 nltk.download()

C:\Users\\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.pyc in download(self, info_or_id, download_dir, quiet, force, prefix, halt_on_error, raise_on_error)
    659             # function should make a new copy of self to use?
    660             if download_dir is not None: self._download_dir = download_dir
--> 661             self._interactive_download()
    662             return True
    663 

C:\Users\\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.pyc in _interactive_download(self)
    980         if TKINTER:
    981             try:
--> 982                 DownloaderGUI(self).mainloop()
    983             except TclError:
    984                 DownloaderShell(self).run()

C:\Users\\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.pyc in mainloop(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1715 
   1716     def mainloop(self, *args, **kwargs):
-> 1717         self.top.mainloop(*args, **kwargs)
   1718 
   1719     #/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

C:\Users\\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.pyc in mainloop(self, n)
   1127     def mainloop(self, n=0):
   1128         """Call the mainloop of Tk."""
-> 1129         self.tk.mainloop(n)
   1130     def quit(self):
   1131         """Quit the Tcl interpreter. All widgets will be destroyed."""

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

command used in jupiter notebook

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

Comment: `nltk.download()` tries to open graphical interface for download. Try to use it without jupyter notebook. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843817/programmatically-install-nltk-corpora-models-i-e-without-the-gui-downloader
There is info how to install it from terminal without gui

Comment: @Konrad. thanks for the correct explanation. I tried Spider notebook and it launched gui. Now I am able to download the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try downloading what you need piece by piece. I actually had this issue and I resolved it by using `nltk.download('name of resource')`

Answer (score 4):

On Jupiter notebook first you have to import nltk

```
import nltk
```

On running below command give you list of packages which you can install

```
nltk.download()
```

then you will see following list of Packages:

```
Download which package (l=list; x=cancel)?
  Identifier> l
Packages:
  [ ] abc................. Australian Broadcasting Commission 2006
  [ ] alpino.............. Alpino Dutch Treebank
  [ ] averaged_perceptron_tagger Averaged Perceptron Tagger
  [ ] averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru Averaged Perceptron Tagger (Russian)
  [ ] basque_grammars..... Grammars for Basque
  [ ] biocreative_ppi..... BioCreAtIvE (Critical Assessment of Information
                           Extraction Systems in Biology)
  [ ] bllip_wsj_no_aux.... BLLIP Parser: WSJ Model
  [ ] book_grammars....... Grammars from NLTK Book
  [ ] brown............... Brown Corpus
  [ ] brown_tei........... Brown Corpus (TEI XML Version)
  [ ] cess_cat............ CESS-CAT Treebank
  [ ] cess_esp............ CESS-ESP Treebank
  [ ] chat80.............. Chat-80 Data Files
  [ ] city_database....... City Database
  [ ] cmudict............. The Carnegie Mellon Pronouncing Dictionary (0.6)
  [ ] comparative_sentences Comparative Sentence Dataset
  [ ] comtrans............ ComTrans Corpus Sample
  [ ] conll2000........... CONLL 2000 Chunking Corpus
  [ ] conll2002........... CONLL 2002 Named Entity Recognition Corpus
Hit Enter to continue: 
  [ ] conll2007........... Dependency Treebanks from CoNLL 2007 (Catalan
                           and Basque Subset)
  [ ] crubadan............ Crubadan Corpus
  [ ] dependency_treebank. Dependency Parsed Treebank
  [ ] dolch............... Dolch Word List
  [ ] europarl_raw........ Sample European Parliament Proceedings Parallel
                           Corpus
  [ ] floresta............ Portuguese Treebank
  [ ] framenet_v15........ FrameNet 1.5
  [ ] framenet_v17........ FrameNet 1.7
  [ ] gazetteers.......... Gazeteer Lists
  [ ] genesis............. Genesis Corpus
  [ ] gutenberg........... Project Gutenberg Selections
  [ ] ieer................ NIST IE-ER DATA SAMPLE
  [ ] inaugural........... C-Span Inaugural Address Corpus
  [ ] indian.............. Indian Language POS-Tagged Corpus
  [ ] jeita............... JEITA Public Morphologically Tagged Corpus (in
                           ChaSen format)
  [ ] kimmo............... PC-KIMMO Data Files
  [ ] knbc................ KNB Corpus (Annotated blog corpus)
  [ ] large_grammars...... Large context-free and feature-based grammars
                           for parser comparison
Hit Enter to continue: 
  [ ] lin_thesaurus....... Lin's Dependency Thesaurus
  [ ] mac_morpho.......... MAC-MORPHO: Brazilian Portuguese news text with
                           part-of-speech tags
  [ ] machado............. Machado de Assis -- Obra Completa
  [ ] masc_tagged......... MASC Tagged Corpus
  [ ] maxent_ne_chunker... ACE Named Entity Chunker (Maximum entropy)
  [ ] maxent_treebank_pos_tagger Treebank Part of Speech Tagger (Maximum entropy)
  [ ] moses_sample........ Moses Sample Models
  [ ] movie_reviews....... Sentiment Polarity Dataset Version 2.0
  [ ] mte_teip5........... MULTEXT-East 1984 annotated corpus 4.0
  [ ] mwa_ppdb............ The monolingual word aligner (Sultan et al.
                           2015) subset of the Paraphrase Database.
  [ ] names............... Names Corpus, Version 1.3 (1994-03-29)
  [ ] nombank.1.0......... NomBank Corpus 1.0
  [ ] nonbreaking_prefixes Non-Breaking Prefixes (Moses Decoder)
  [ ] nps_chat............ NPS Chat
  [ ] omw................. Open Multilingual Wordnet
  [ ] opinion_lexicon..... Opinion Lexicon
  [ ] panlex_swadesh...... PanLex Swadesh Corpora
  [ ] paradigms........... Paradigm Corpus
  [ ] pe08................ Cross-Framework and Cross-Domain Parser
                           Evaluation Shared Task
Hit Enter to continue: 
  [ ] perluniprops........ perluniprops: Index of Unicode Version 7.0.0
                           character properties in Perl
  [ ] pil................. The Patient Information Leaflet (PIL) Corpus
  [ ] pl196x.............. Polish language of the XX century sixties
  [ ] porter_test......... Porter Stemmer Test Files
  [ ] ppattach............ Prepositional Phrase Attachment Corpus
  [ ] problem_reports..... Problem Report Corpus
  [ ] product_reviews_1... Product Reviews (5 Products)
  [ ] product_reviews_2... Product Reviews (9 Products)
  [ ] propbank............ Proposition Bank Corpus 1.0
  [ ] pros_cons........... Pros and Cons
  [ ] ptb................. Penn Treebank
  [ ] punkt............... Punkt Tokenizer Models
  [ ] qc.................. Experimental Data for Question Classification
  [ ] reuters............. The Reuters-21578 benchmark corpus, ApteMod
                           version
  [ ] rslp................ RSLP Stemmer (Removedor de Sufixos da Lingua
                           Portuguesa)
  [ ] rte................. PASCAL RTE Challenges 1, 2, and 3
  [ ] sample_grammars..... Sample Grammars
  [ ] semcor.............. SemCor 3.0
Hit Enter to continue: 
  [ ] senseval............ SENSEVAL 2 Corpus: Sense Tagged Text
  [ ] sentence_polarity... Sentence Polarity Dataset v1.0
  [ ] sentiwordnet........ SentiWordNet
  [ ] shakespeare......... Shakespeare XML Corpus Sample
  [ ] sinica_treebank..... Sinica Treebank Corpus Sample
  [ ] smultron............ SMULTRON Corpus Sample
  [ ] snowball_data....... Snowball Data
  [ ] spanish_grammars.... Grammars for Spanish
  [ ] state_union......... C-Span State of the Union Address Corpus
  [ ] stopwords........... Stopwords Corpus
  [ ] subjectivity........ Subjectivity Dataset v1.0
  [ ] swadesh............. Swadesh Wordlists
  [ ] switchboard......... Switchboard Corpus Sample
  [ ] tagsets............. Help on Tagsets
  [ ] timit............... TIMIT Corpus Sample
  [ ] toolbox............. Toolbox Sample Files
  [ ] treebank............ Penn Treebank Sample
  [ ] twitter_samples..... Twitter Samples
  [ ] udhr2............... Universal Declaration of Human Rights Corpus
                           (Unicode Version)
  [ ] udhr................ Universal Declaration of Human Rights Corpus
Hit Enter to continue: 
  [ ] unicode_samples..... Unicode Samples
  [ ] universal_tagset.... Mappings to the Universal Part-of-Speech Tagset
  [ ] universal_treebanks_v20 Universal Treebanks Version 2.0
  [ ] vader_lexicon....... VADER Sentiment Lexicon
  [ ] verbnet3............ VerbNet Lexicon, Version 3.3
  [ ] verbnet............. VerbNet Lexicon, Version 2.1
  [ ] webtext............. Web Text Corpus
  [ ] wmt15_eval.......... Evaluation data from WMT15
  [ ] word2vec_sample..... Word2Vec Sample
  [ ] wordnet............. WordNet
  [ ] wordnet_ic.......... WordNet-InfoContent
  [ ] words............... Word Lists
  [ ] ycoe................ York-Toronto-Helsinki Parsed Corpus of Old
                           English Prose

Collections:
  [ ] all-corpora......... All the corpora
  [ ] all-nltk............ All packages available on nltk_data gh-pages
                           branch
  [ ] all................. All packages
  [ ] book................ Everything used in the NLTK Book
  [ ] popular............. Popular packages
Hit Enter to continue: 
  [ ] tests............... Packages for running tests
  [ ] third-party......... Third-party data packages
```

Then you can choose your package which you need for example you choose "vader_lexicon"

```
nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
```

you can also install all package by passing  all................. All packages

```
nltk.download('all')
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your terminal and run "ipython"

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

Follow the guide and this will affect your notebook

Comment: it will try to download everything.