# POS tagging german text using NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, part-of-speech

I would like to use NLTK for pos tagging german texts. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639855/nltk-tagging-in-german) and [this project](https://github.com/japerk/nltk-trainer). Both look quite complicated and I cannot find some NLTK documentation about how to train pos taggers. Any hint? I'm looking for the most simple way to put in some german text and to get back tagged words. Any hint?

Comment: [This](http://experimentallabor.de/) looks like it could help you. They train a classifier-based POS-Tagger on the NEGRA-format and get quite good results. You should read the 3-4 blog posts they posted there, they give code examples too.

Comment: Since the mentioned website experimentallabor.de is not available any more, you should check this out: https://datascience.blog.wzb.eu/2016/07/13/accurate-part-of-speech-tagging-of-german-texts-with-nltk/

Answer (score 5):

The Stanford tagger is trained on German.
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml

Answer (score 0):

[TreeTagger](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/) can be used for a bunch of languages, including German. However, it cannot be used for commercial purposes.