# Named-entity recognition: How to tag the training set and chose the algorithm?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition, pos-tagger

For text that contains company names I want to train a model that automatically tags contractors (company executing the task) and principals (company hiring the contractor).

An example sentence would be:

> Blossom Inc. hires the consultants of Big Think to develop an outsourcing strategy.

with *Blossom Inc* as the principal and *Big Think* as the contractor.

My first question: **Is it enough to tag only the principals and contractors in my training set or is it better to additionally use POS-tagging?**

In other words, either

> Blossom/PRINCIPAL Inc./PRINCIPAL hires/NN the/NN consultants/NN of/NN Big/CONTRACTOR Think/CONTRACTOR to/NN develop/NN an/NN outsourcing/NN strategy/NN ./.

or

> Blossom/PRINCIPAL Inc./PRINCIPAL hires/VBZ the/DT consultants/NNS of/IN Big/CONTRACTOR Think/CONTRACTOR to/TO develop/VB an/DT outsourcing/NN strategy/NN ./.

Second question: **Once I have my training set, which algorithm(s) of the nltk-package is/are most promising?** N-Gram Tagger, Brill Tagger, TnT Tagger, Maxent Classifier, Naive Bayes, ...? Or am I completely on the wrong track here?

I am new to NLP and I just wanted to ask for advice before I invest a lot of time in tagging my training set. And my text is in German, which might add some difficulties... Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise you not to merge named entities and POS information. Most work has showed that POS (or otherwise some morphological and/or capitalization features) is valuable for detecting named entities. As you can quite safely use an automatic POS tagger (unless you process noisy texts), you may end up with something like:

```
Blossom/NNP/PRINCIPAL Inc./NNP/PRINCIPAL hires/VBZ/O the/DT/O consultants/NNS/O of/IN/O Big/NNP/CONTRACTOR Think/NNP/CONTRACTOR to/TO/O develop/VB/O an/DT/O outsourcing/NN/O strategy/NN/O ./.
```

where POS level would be automatically tagged while you can manually annotate PRINCIPAL and CONTRACTOR. Also note that most people use [BIO format](http://code.google.com/p/cleartk/wiki/TutorialNamedEntityChunkingClassifier) for tagging named entities.

Keep in mind that recognizing organizations is usually quite hard - at least harder than persons and locations. Unless you have a predefined list of organizations, large lexicon are required for this. Intuitivelly, I guess you could divide your task in:

1. Recognize and filtering organizations (ORG), for instance by using a NER tagger
2. Inject additional processings (patterns/syntax/semantics)
3. Implement a second model that transform relevant ORG in PRINCIPAL or CONTRACTOR

Comment: `Most work has shown` sounds fluffy, and I know for a fact that it's not true. Not to mention you're implying that POS is a morphological feature, and that capitalization is comparably to POS, neither of which is true.

Comment: Have a look there http://l2r.cs.uiuc.edu/~danr/Papers/RatinovRo09.pdf about NER/POS. Also, I do not imply POS is a morphological feature, but that for NER, if you don't use POS (which gives you NNPs), you'll have to use some morphological features or at least capitalization.

Comment: That paper shows POS as an example of a feature that might be used. Very different from saying that POS tagging is required. Also standard POS taggers (specifically the one in NLTK) typically only hit ~60-70% accuracy on new text, so building NER on it is kind of like building a castle on sand. Also your second point is like saying: If you don't use this feature you have to use some other feature. Conll (the most prevalent NER corpus) doesn't contain POS, which makes this a pretty moot point.

Comment: Should I really argue? Quote from cited paper: "Most NER systems use additional features, such as POS tags, shallow parsing information and gazetteers". CoNLL data format do contain POS: http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2003/ner/ . Nonetheless, let me slightly modify my answer to take into account your comment.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to POS tag manually. The POS tagger will do it for you.
2. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1639855/907578) for POS tagging German.

Answer (score 0):

Named Entity Recognition(Stanford) is enough for your problem.

Using POS tagging will not help your problem.

A sufficient amount of training data for generating the NER model would give you good results.

If you use the Stanford NER then it uses the CRF classifier and algorithm.